# Server returned HTTP response code: 500 with HttpUrlConnection in Android

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I am `Post`ing some data into a specific `URL` by using the following code:

```
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class LookupPOST {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
        String accountlookup = "<account>"+
                                "<name>N*</name>"+
                                "<type></type>"+
                                "<accountaddress>"+
                                    "<address></address>"+
                                    "<state></state>"+
                                    "<zip></zip>"+
                                    "<city></city>"+
                                    "<country></country>"+
                                    "<county></county>"+
                                "</accountaddress>"+
                               "</account>";

        URL url = new URL(" http://localhost:8080/Sfacgi/accounts/lookUpaccount");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("authenticate", "BBUSER1:BBUSER1");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
        connection.setRequestProperty("pinno", "2526121F96");
        connection.setRequestProperty("appversion", "BBV15");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);

         OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
         writer.write(accountlookup);
         writer.close();

         if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) 
         {
             System.out.println(" Success ");
         } 
         else 
         {
             System.out.println("Server returned HTTP error code :"+connection.getResponseCode());
         }

}}
```

It sucessfully posts, but when I retrieve the data, it gives me the following error:

```
Excpetion = java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost:8080/Sfacgi/accounts/lookUpaccount
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost:88080/Sfacgi/accounts/lookUpaccount
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1403)
at com.jp.look.LookupGet.main(LookupGet.java:31)
```

I am using the following code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class LookupGet 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{   
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/Sfacgi/accounts/lookUpaccount");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("authenticate", "BBUSER1:BBUSER1");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
        connection.setRequestProperty("pinno", "2526121F96");
        connection.setRequestProperty("appversion", "BBV15");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        int timeoutMs=500000;
        connection.setConnectTimeout(timeoutMs);
        connection.setReadTimeout(timeoutMs);

        //InputStream is = url.openStream();

        InputStream is1 = connection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is1));

            String data;

            while ((data = reader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                 System.out.println(data);
            }
            reader.close();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(" Excpetion = " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();        
    }
}}
```

Can anyone tell me where I am wrong in my code? Any suggestions.

Comment: What happens if you send the request with the browser? Does the GET request work in general?

Comment: you  are using a localhost url may b it unable to connect so, first try that url on device browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Localhost is accessible as you are able to do the post call.
2. The error code 500 indicates that your sever is not able to handle the request, due to any reason. main be some exception or URL is not mapped.
3. Incase of exception read the ErrorStream method instead of Inputstream to know about the error
   Example
    connection.getErrorStream()

Answer (score 1):

By seeing your code i think You are trying to read data from your `localHost` 
If want connection to your localhost you have to specify **`IP Address`** of your computer
for example

```
URL url = new URL("http://IPAddressOfComputer/Sfacgi/accounts/lookUpaccount");
```